# Error when converting jar from eclipse to exe with launch4j

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have created a jar file from my java swing application using Eclipse IDE, I wonder how to run it without using eclipse or cmd. Eventually I found that I can create an exe with Launch4j, after a couple of tutorial I get this error as shown in link of screen shots below while launching the exe.

It works fine when I run it on my laptop which has JRE installed, while I run it on my friend's laptop which has no JRE it shows error. So I used bundled to handle this, I copied the jre from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211 to my application's folder and set the bundle path in Lauch4j. But when I compile it, there's warning message pops up at Lauch4j log which is "Sign the executable to minimize antivirus false positives or use launching instead of wrapping.". When I tried to run the exe file, it shows "a jni error has occurred please check your installation and try again"

How to fix this error?

Here are the screen shots when I create it with Lauch4j

https://paste.pics/61J4Y
https://paste.pics/61J9K

Answer (score 0):

I guess setting up the environmental variable could resolve this problem. More over be more specific with the question, so that i could help better.Thanks

Comment: I have edited the question, it's mainly about how to run jar in exe without JRE intalled manually

Answer (score 0):

Bundling the JRE is not a good idea. Always ask the user to install java OR give a installation guide/UI in the app. JRE can vary for different machines. For eg. you could have bundled a 64-bit JRE, but if you try to run that on a 32-bit windows it will create errors.

I think the JRE type and version is creating this problem in the target machine.

Comment: so can I create something like auto-install JRE from the application, assume that the user don't have any knowledge about installing JRE. It will help much a lot right? Or perhaps there is other way to run jar without installing JRE manually from the user path? @Kris

Comment: Without JRE you cannot execute a java application. But if you want that to be bundled -probably make 32 bit jre bundle. Refer this answer https://superuser.com/questions/745112/how-do-i-run-a-jar-file-without-installing-java  - is a bit old one, but seems to work.

Comment: I have tried that way, when the jPortable finished the download and ask to select a jar. I select the jar and try to open the JPortable, but it keep asking me to choose a jar even though I have choose a couple times. @Kris